# split digits and alpha

Tags: javascript, regex, split, alpha, digits

I need to split a string like this: ID00605button.
I want to get out ID00605.
my code example:

```
    var contentLeftID;
    var id = "ID00605button"
    id = id.split(*some regex*);

    contentLeftID = id[0] + id[1];
```

Is it somebody how knows to write a regex to get ID00605?

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Do you have more examples, or is the pattern same where you split where digits end?

Comment: It is easy with `match`: `"ID00605button".match(/[a-zA-Z]+\d+/)`

Comment: yes, it´s JS and the pattern are same.

Comment: if i use your solution @Wiktor Stribiżew with match, will the console.log(contentLeftID) writes: 

 ["ID000006", index: 0, input: "ID000006cntButtons"]

how did I get the first value? id[0] does not work.

Comment: `"ID00605button".match(/[a-zA-Z]+\d+/)[0]`. You can implement additional checks, like `var t = "ID00605button"; var m = t.match(/[a-zA-Z]+\d+/); if (m) { alert(m[0]); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var contentLeftID;
var id = "ID00605button";
id = id.match(/(ID\d+)(.*)/);
contentLeftID = id[1] + id[2];
```

`id.match(/(ID\d+)(.*)/)` returns an array:

```
[ "ID00605button", "ID00605", "button" ]
```

Comment: thanks @Jahid this work when i did a null check! Thanks a lot!